# ON DELETE CASCADE in sqlite3

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following structure: (Sorry for awkward names, it is because it is a sqlite database for my iPhone app which is not released yet)

```
CREATE TABLE klb_log (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
  log_comment varchar(512)
)

CREATE TABLE klb_log_food_maps (
  uid integer,
  did integer,
  PRIMARY KEY (uid,did),
  FOREIGN KEY (uid) references klb_log(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (did) references klb_food(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
)

CREATE TABLE klb_food (
  id integer,
  description varchar(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Is there a reason why the row in `klb_log_food_maps` is not removed when I delete a row in `klb_log`?

Comment: Did you solve this? I am having the same problem, even after running the "PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON" query.

Comment: @PiotrBlasiak Yes, I run this before doing any queries against the database:  if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, "PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON", -1, &enableForeignKey, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
                NSLog(@"ERROR IN PRAGMA DBADAPTER!");
            }

            sqlite3_finalize(enableForeignKey); AND This are variables: static sqlite3 *database;
static sqlite3_stmt *enableForeignKey;

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Foreign key support is not enabled in SQLite by default.  You need to enable it manually each time you connect to the database using the pragma:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON
```

Comment: Hi, do I just run it as a normal query?

Comment: Yes, run it as a normal query.

Comment: is it necesary everytime I want to insert, update and delete records or just while my full schema creation?

Comment: I've found I've had to do the PRAGMA command right after I connect to the database, but not before each DB command.

Comment: once per database session (i.e. once per invocation of /usr/class/cs145/bin/sqlite). Even if you have previously enabled foreign key constraint checking while using a particular database, new sessions with that database will not check foreign key constraints unless you issue this PRAGMA command. If you do not issue this command, foreign key constraints are permitted to become violated, and it will happen in complete silence.
by http://cs.stanford.edu/people/widom/cs145/sqlite/SQLiteRefIntegrity.html

Answer (score 16):

Do you have foreign key support enabled?

query `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;` to turn it on

Comment: If I just run that as a normal query, then that did not help unfortunately.

Comment: what does sqlite3_libversion() give you?

Comment: Hi, sorry late response. It give me 3.7.2