# Laravel - onDelete("cascade") does not work

Tags: php, sqlite, laravel, laravel-4, database-migration

I have an `Laravel 4` app with polls and different options or choices to vote. The problem is that when I destroy a poll, the options are not deleted from the database.

These are my main migrations:

**Polls:**

```
private $table = 'polls';

public function down() {
    Schema::dropIfExists($this->table);
}

public function up() {
    Schema::create($this->table, function(Blueprint $table) {

        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string( 'owner'      )->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('owner'      )->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->string( 'topic'      );
        $table->boolean('multichoice')->default(false);
        $table->boolean('signed'     )->default(false); // Marks if the poll can be voted only by authenticated users
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**Options:**

```
private $table = 'options';

public function down() {
    Schema::dropIfExists($this->table);
}

public function up() {
    Schema::create($this->table, function(Blueprint $table) {

        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer(   'poll_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign(   'poll_id')->references('id')->on('polls')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->string(    'name'   );
        $table->integer(   'votes'  )->default(0);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

And this is the code that deletes:

```
    Poll::destroy($id);
```

I am using `sqlite` as my DB enging right now.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe sqlite has foreign key support disabled (default behaviour).

See [ON DELETE CASCADE in sqlite3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890250/on-delete-cascade-in-sqlite3)

Comment: Indeed! I found this: http://trzebinski.info/allow-sqlite-to-use-foreign-keys-in-laravel-4/ I will try it out and report