# Creating related tables in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am creating related tables in SQLite and am wondering what the most efficient way to make them relate to each other is.

```
CREATE TABLE cards_name (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, rarity TEXT);
CREATE TABLE card_story (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name_id INTEGER, story TEXT);
```

I have already entered some data for the first table and I was wondering how to add data to the second table without having to look up what the INTEGER PRIMARY KEY is every time (perhaps by using the cards name??)

```
26|Armorsmith|Rare
27|Auchenai Soulpriest|Rare
28|Avenging Wrath|Epic
29|Bane of Doom|Epic
```

For instance, I would like to enter the story of Armorsmith as "She accepts guild funds for repairs!" into story TEXT by using her name(Armorsmith) instead of ID(26).

Thanks

Comment: you could check this link https://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html

Comment: INTEGER ID is recommended.  However, it sounds like you're just having a data entry problem.  Usually I import raw data into "staging" tables kind of as-is without ID etc.  Then I run some queries to move the data from staging into the target tables which are in the format I want.  e.g. `INSERT INTO staging_story('ArmorSmith', 'She accepts guild funds for repairs!')` which just has `card_name` and `story_story` fields.  Looking up by `card_name` is slow, but only happens once on first data import.

Answer (score 0):

The task you are describing should be taken care of on the application level, not on database level.

You can create a GUI where you can select the name of a card, but the underlying value sent back to the database is the card's id and that gets stored in the story table establishing the relationship between the card and the story.

Answer (score 0):

> *I would like to enter the story of Armorsmith as "She accepts guild funds for repairs!" into story TEXT by using her name(Armorsmith) instead of ID(26).*

You can insert into one table from another table. Instead of hard coding the values, you can get them from a select. So long as the rows returned by the select match the rows needed by the insert it'll work.

```
insert into cards_story
    (name_id, story)
    select id, :story
    from cards_name
    where name = :name
```

The insert needs an ID and a story. The select returns ids and we've added our own text field for the story.

This statement would be executed with two parameters, one containing the text of the story, and one containing the name of the person. So you might write something like this (the exact details depend on your programming language and SQL interface library).

```
sql.execute(
    name: "Armorsmith",
    story: "She accepts guild funds for repairs!"
)
```

Is the equivalent of:

```
insert into cards_story
    (name_id, story)
    select id, 'She accepts guild funds for repairs!'
    from cards_name
    where name = 'Armorsmith'
```

---

Note that you'll want to make a few changes to your schema...

- Declare name `unique` else you might get multiple cards for one name.

Like `name TEXT UNIQUE`.

Since you're looking up cards by name, you probably want to prevent there being multiple cards with the same name. That's just complexity you don't need to deal with.

- Declare your foreign keys.

Like `name_id INTEGER REFERENCES cards_name(id)`.

This has multiple benefits. One is keys are automatically indexed, so looking up stories by name_id will be faster.

The other is it enforces "referential integrity" which is a fancy way of saying it makes sure that every story has a name to go with it. If you try to delete a `card_name` it will balk unless the `card_story` is deleted first. You can also use things like [`on delete cascade`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890250/on-delete-cascade-in-sqlite3#5901100) to do the cleanup for you.

However, SQLite does not have foreign keys on by default. You have to turn them on. It's a very good idea to do so.