# codeigniter 3, sqlite3 : delete query builder cascade not working

Tags: php, sqlite, cascade

cuirrently im using CodeIgniter-3.1.13 as my framework, and sqlite3 as my db driver
i tried to delete a recor on my database using usual delte query builder, the problem is, the fopreign key contrain doesnt work, what i mean is, when i delete certain data on parrent table, the data on child table doesnt get deleted as well. but when i tried to delete a reord freom table parrent from db browser sql command, it worked

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "attendance";
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "attendance" (
    "attendance_id" INTEGER,
    "employee_id"   INTEGER,
    "attendance_date"   TEXT,
    "clock_in_time" TEXT,
    "clock_out_time"    TEXT,
    FOREIGN KEY("employee_id") REFERENCES "employee"("employee_id"),
    PRIMARY KEY("attendance_id")
);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "department";
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "department" (
    "department_id" INTEGER,
    "department_name"   TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY("department_id")
);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "employee";
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "employee" (
    "employee_id"   INTEGER,
    "first_name"    TEXT,
    "last_name" TEXT,
    "date_of_birth" TEXT,
    "gender"    TEXT,
    "contact_number"    TEXT,
    "email" TEXT,
    "address"   TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY("employee_id")
);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "employeeleave";
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "employeeleave" (
    "leave_id"  INTEGER,
    "employee_id"   INTEGER,
    "leave_type"    TEXT,
    "start_date"    TEXT,
    "end_date"  TEXT,
    "status"    TEXT,
    FOREIGN KEY("employee_id") REFERENCES "employee"("employee_id"),
    PRIMARY KEY("leave_id")
);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "jobposition";
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "jobposition" (
    "position_id"   INTEGER,
    "position_name" TEXT,
    "base_salary"   REAL,
    PRIMARY KEY("position_id")
);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "payroll";
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "payroll" (
    "payroll_id"    INTEGER,
    "employee_id"   INTEGER,
    "salary_month"  TEXT,
    "salary_year"   INTEGER,
    "total_salary"  REAL,
    "deductions"    REAL,
    "bonuses"   REAL,
    "net_salary"    REAL,
    FOREIGN KEY("employee_id") REFERENCES "employee"("employee_id"),
    PRIMARY KEY("payroll_id")
);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "earning_type";
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "earning_type" (
    "earning_type_id"   INTEGER,
    "type_name" TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY("earning_type_id")
);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "earnings";
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "earnings" (
    "earning_id"    INTEGER,
    "payroll_id"    INTEGER,
    "earning_type_id"   INTEGER,
    "amount"    REAL,
    FOREIGN KEY("payroll_id") REFERENCES "payroll"("payroll_id"),
    FOREIGN KEY("earning_type_id") REFERENCES "earning_type"("earning_type_id"),
    PRIMARY KEY("earning_id")
);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "deduction_type";
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "deduction_type" (
    "deduction_type_id" INTEGER,
    "type_name" TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY("deduction_type_id")
);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "deductions";
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "deductions" (
    "deduction_id"  INTEGER,
    "payroll_id"    INTEGER,
    "deduction_type_id" INTEGER,
    "amount"    REAL,
    PRIMARY KEY("deduction_id"),
    FOREIGN KEY("payroll_id") REFERENCES "payroll"("payroll_id"),
    FOREIGN KEY("deduction_type_id") REFERENCES "deduction_type"("deduction_type_id")
);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "department_jobposition";
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "department_jobposition" (
    "department_id" INTEGER,
    "position_id"   INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY("department_id","position_id"),
    FOREIGN KEY("department_id") REFERENCES "department"("department_id") ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY("position_id") REFERENCES "jobposition"("position_id") ON DELETE CASCADE
);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "employee_department";
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "employee_department" (
    "employee_id"   INTEGER,
    "department_id" INTEGER,
    "start_date"    TEXT,
    "end_date"  TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY("employee_id","department_id"),
    FOREIGN KEY("employee_id") REFERENCES "employee"("employee_id") ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY("department_id") REFERENCES "department"("department_id") ON DELETE CASCADE
);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "employee_jobposition";
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "employee_jobposition" (
    "employee_id"   INTEGER,
    "position_id"   INTEGER,
    "start_date"    TEXT,
    "end_date"  TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY("employee_id","position_id"),
    FOREIGN KEY("position_id") REFERENCES "jobposition"("position_id") ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY("employee_id") REFERENCES "employee"("employee_id") ON DELETE CASCADE
);
INSERT INTO "department" VALUES (2,'Apotek');
INSERT INTO "employee" VALUES (1,'yaya','yeye','2021-08-22','Perempuan','0822261672','yayayeye@gmail.com','sungai ayak');
INSERT INTO "employee" VALUES (2,'rara','rere','2023-03-27','Perempuan','0882342','rararere@gmai.com','sungai ayak');
INSERT INTO "jobposition" VALUES (1,'dokter',NULL);
INSERT INTO "jobposition" VALUES (2,'bidan',NULL);
INSERT INTO "jobposition" VALUES (3,'apoteker',NULL);
INSERT INTO "earning_type" VALUES (1,'Overtime');
INSERT INTO "earning_type" VALUES (2,'Bonus');
INSERT INTO "deduction_type" VALUES (1,'Tax');
INSERT INTO "deduction_type" VALUES (2,'Insurance');
INSERT INTO "department_jobposition" VALUES (1,1);
INSERT INTO "department_jobposition" VALUES (1,2);
INSERT INTO "department_jobposition" VALUES (2,3);
INSERT INTO "employee_department" VALUES (1,1,'2023-12-01','');
INSERT INTO "employee_department" VALUES (2,2,'2023-12-01','');
INSERT INTO "employee_jobposition" VALUES (1,2,'2023-12-08','');
COMMIT;


    $active_group = 'default';
    $query_builder = TRUE;

    $db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => '',
    'username' => '',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => './application/maria_ems.db',
    'dbdriver' => 'sqlite3',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
        'failover' => array(),
        'save_queries' => TRUE,
    'dbdriver_options' => array(
        'sqlite3' => array(
            'dbdriver' => 'sqlite3',
            'database' => APPPATH . 'maria_ems.db',
            'dbprefix' => '',
            'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
            'cache_on' => FALSE,
            'cachedir' => '',
            'char_set' => 'utf8',
            'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
            'swap_pre' => '',
            'encrypt' => FALSE,
            'compress' => FALSE,
            'stricton' => FALSE,
            'failover' => array(),
            'save_queries' => TRUE,
            'flags' => SQLITE3_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE3_OPEN_CREATE,
            'pragma' => array(
                'foreign_keys' => TRUE, // Example pragma setting
                // Add other pragma settings as needed
            ),
        ),
    )
);

public function delete_data_department($id)
    {

        try {
            $this->db->trans_start(); // Start transaction
    
            // Enable foreign keys using PRAGMA
            $this->db->query('PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON');
    
            $this->db->where('department_id', $id);
            $this->db->delete('department');
    
            if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {            
                $this->db->trans_commit(); // Commit transaction
                echo "Data Berhasil dihapus!";            
            } else {
                $this->db->trans_rollback(); // Rollback transaction
                http_response_code(400);
                echo json_encode(["error" => "Ada yang tidak beres, hubungi developer anda!"]);
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            // Handle exceptions, if any
            $this->db->trans_rollback(); // Rollback transaction
            http_response_code(500);
            echo json_encode(["error" => $e->getMessage()]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ON DELETE CASCADE in sqlite3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890250/on-delete-cascade-in-sqlite3)

Comment: PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON, ive tried using this on my query, still doesnt work, i edited my question to include my controller code

Comment: Could it be due to the transaction/rollbacks? Have you tried a minimal example? Does your code return `echo "Data Berhasil dihapus!";`?

Comment: yes it does return "Data berhasil!", but every coresponden row on child table doesnt get deleted

Comment: Turn on trace logging for the database, see what the queries sent are. Perhaps CI is generting a query that's not cascading with SQLite.

Comment: Are you able to dump your table, please, looks like foreign keys with their constraints aren't setup at all. CI does not support foreign keys in models and will not set them up as far as the documentation says, so unless you've set them up yourself it won't work.

Comment: i included my database in my question, the foreign key constraint is setup accordingly